# 3d draw, setting perspective point, setting view point!

Tags: java, opengl

I need to draw 3d projections and i am using opengl wrapper for JAVA.
Problem: 
        - how to set view point in java opengl (for examle i want to my program to draw object on screen like i am looking at that object from (0,0,0) )
        - how to set perspective point(point in 3d where look is heading to, for example i want may program to draw object on screen as i am looking from (0, 0, 0) to (1, 1, 3) )

I am familiarized with mathematical problem of this question, so i have calculated all of the coordinates for perspectives. I just need opengl java function or set off functions that can draw this new coordinates in perspective i want.

HELP!! :)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Nehe](http://nehe.gamedev.net/lesson.asp?index=01) have a port of most of their tutorials to Java. One of the first one should probably be doing what you need to get yourself started.

Answer (score 2):

Does this [example](http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/jogl/how-to-render-a-wireframe-cube.html) help you? The function you are perhaps looking for is [gluLookAt](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/man_pages/hardcopy/GL/html/glu/lookat.html):

```
gluLookAt( GLdouble eyeX,
       GLdouble eyeY,
       GLdouble eyeZ,
       GLdouble centerX,
       GLdouble centerY,
       GLdouble centerZ,
       GLdouble upX,
       GLdouble upY,
       GLdouble upZ )

PARAMETERS
  eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ
      Specifies the position of the eye point.

  centerX, centerY, centerZ
      Specifies the position of the reference
          point.

  upX, upY, upZ   
          Specifies the direction of the up vector.
```

Comment: tnx a lot!! This was very helpful..i when i found out function everything worked out..:))

Answer (score 0):

Try this tutorial on Java and OpenGL

[Java Personal OpenGL Tutorial](http://www.cs.uwm.edu/~grafix2/)

Comment: Tnx. As i am new to this combination(java/opengl) this was helpfull. :))